# Specify Log file when setting up ICE communicator

Tags: c++, ice

When initializing an ICE communicator, is it possibly to specify a different log file than what is named in the config file?  I want to change where Ice.StdOut and Ice.StdErr log too programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help http://www.zeroc.com/doc/Ice-3.3.1/manual/Adv_server.33.20.html